Multiple Actions when model is learning in from Stable Baselines 3
I have a game model with multiple entities that move around in 2 dimensions. I have an action space vector that is 4*number of entities.
I would like at each step in the model to move all of the entities with the actions vector, instead of moving 1 entity each time.
It works as the test function, but it does not work in the learning phase.
The general code is below, please recommend some suggestions to make this work. Thank you.
import gym
from gym import spaces
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
import itertools
from stable_baselines3.common.env_checker import check_env
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
import os

num_squares = 30
square_size = 20
models_dir = "models/square/"
log_dir = "logs/square/"


class SquareGameEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SquareGameEnv, self).__init__()

        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600

        # Define the observation space with dtype as np.uint16
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=800, shape=(num_squares * 6,), dtype=np.uint16)

        # Define the action space size
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(4 * num_squares)

        self.squares = []

    def random_color(self):
        colors = [(0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), (255, 0, 0)]  # Green, Blue, Red
        return random.choice(colors)

    def create_square(self, img):
        x = np.random.randint(0, img.shape[1] - square_size, dtype=np.uint16)
        y = np.random.randint(0, img.shape[0] - square_size, dtype=np.uint16)
        color = self.random_color()
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + square_size, y + square_size), color, -1)
        return (x, y, square_size, color)

    def collide(self, square1, square2, square3):
        x1, y1, size1, _ = square1
        x2, y2, size2, _ = square2
        x3, y3, size3, _ = square3

        # Calculate distances between squares
        distance1 = (x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2
        distance2 = (x1 - x3) ** 2 + (y1 - y3) ** 2
        distance3 = (x2 - x3) ** 2 + (y2 - y3) ** 2

        # Check if all distances are below the threshold
        if distance1 < (size1 + size2)**2 and distance2 < (size1 + size3)**2 and distance3 < (size2 + size3)**2:
            return True
        return False

    def step(self, actions):
        # Ensure actions is an iterable
        if not isinstance(actions, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)):
            actions = [actions]
    
        # Define action mapping
        action_mapping = {
            0: (0, -5),   # Up
            1: (0, 5),    # Down
            2: (-5, 0),   # Left
            3: (5, 0)     # Right
        }
    
        # Apply actions to move squares
        for i, action in enumerate(actions):
            # Determine which square to move based on action index
            square_index = i // 4
            move_direction = action % 4
    
            # Move the selected square based on the action
            x, y, size, color = self.squares[square_index]
            dx, dy = action_mapping[move_direction]
    
            # Update square position
            x += dx
            y += dy
    
            # Check boundaries
            if x < 0:
                x = 0
            elif x + size > self.width:
                x = self.width - size
            if y < 0:
                y = 0
            elif y + size > self.height:
                y = self.height - size
    
            self.squares[square_index] = (x, y, size, color)
    
        # Check collisions
        for i, j, k in itertools.combinations(range(len(self.squares)), 3):
            # Check if square1 and square2 collide and have the same color
            if self.collide(self.squares[i], self.squares[j], self.squares[k]) and self.squares[j][3] == self.squares[k][3]:
                self.squares[i] = (self.squares[i][0], self.squares[i][1], self.squares[i][2], self.squares[j][3])
            # Check if square2 and square3 collide and have the same color
            elif self.collide(self.squares[j], self.squares[i], self.squares[k]) and self.squares[i][3] == self.squares[k][3]:
                self.squares[j] = (self.squares[j][0], self.squares[j][1], self.squares[j][2], self.squares[i][3])
            # Check if square1 and square3 collide and have the same color
            elif self.collide(self.squares[k], self.squares[i], self.squares[j]) and self.squares[i][3] == self.squares[j][3]:
                self.squares[k] = (self.squares[k][0], self.squares[k][1], self.squares[k][2], self.squares[i][3])
    
        # Count number of blue and red squares
        num_blue = sum(1 for _, _, _, c in self.squares if c == (0, 0, 255))
        num_red = sum(1 for _, _, _, c in self.squares if c == (255, 0, 0))
    
        # Calculate reward as the difference between blue and red squares
        reward = (num_blue - num_red)
        print("reward",reward)
        
        #if num_red > num_blue:
        #    reward = 1
        #elif num_blue > num_red:
        #    reward = -1
        #else:
        #    reward = 0
    
        # Update observation
        observation = self.get_observation()
    
        # Check if game is done
        done = (num_red == 0 or num_blue == 0) 
    
        # Additional information, if needed
        info = {}
    
        return observation, reward, done, info


    def reset(self):
        # Reset squares
        self.squares = []
        for _ in range(num_squares):
            self.squares.append(self.create_square(np.zeros((self.height, self.width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)))

        # Return initial observation
        return self.get_observation()

    def get_observation(self):
        # Extract positions, size, and color of each square
        observation = np.zeros((num_squares, 6), dtype=np.uint16)
        for i, square in enumerate(self.squares):
            x, y, size, color = square
            observation[i] = x, y, size, color[0], color[1], color[2]
        return observation.flatten()

    def render(self, mode='rgb_array'):
        # Render the squares
        image = np.zeros((self.height, self.width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        for square in self.squares:
            x, y, size, color = square
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + size, y + size), color, -1)
        if mode == 'rgb_array':
            return image
        elif mode == 'human':
            cv2.imshow('Game', image)
            cv2.waitKey(30)  # Small delay for rendering
        else:
            super(SquareGameEnv, self).render(mode=mode)

    def close(self):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


# Testing the environment
def test():
    env = SquareGameEnv()
    check_env(env)
    episodes = 1
    
    for episode in range(episodes):
        done = False
        obs = env.reset()
        while not done:
            random_actions = [random.randint(0, 3) for _ in range(4 * num_squares)]
            obs, reward, done, info = env.step(random_actions)
            env.render(mode='human')


def learn():
    if not os.path.exists(models_dir):
        os.makedirs(models_dir)

    if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
        os.makedirs(log_dir)

    env = SquareGameEnv()
    check_env(env)
    env.reset()

    model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_dir)

    TIMESTEPS = 10
    episodes = 10
    iters = 0
    for i in range(episodes):
        iters += 1
        model.learn(total_timesteps=TIMESTEPS, reset_num_timesteps=False)
        model.save(f"{models_dir}/{TIMESTEPS * iters}")
        print("episode ", i)


def play():
    env = SquareGameEnv()
    env.display = True
    env.reset()

    model_path = f"{models_dir}/1000.zip"
    model = PPO.load(model_path, env=env)

    episodes = 50

    for ep in range(episodes):
        obs = env.reset()
        done = False
        while not done:
            action, _states = model.predict(obs)
            obs, rewards, done, info = env.step(action)
            print(rewards)


test()
learn()

The requirements.txt file is below, it has some other packages
decorator==5.1.1
exceptiongroup==1.2.1
executing==2.0.1
Farama-Notifications==0.0.4
filelock==3.13.1
fonttools==4.51.0
fsspec==2024.2.0
grpcio==1.63.0
gym==0.21.0
gym-notices==0.0.8
gymnasium==0.29.1
intel-openmp==2021.4.0
ipython==8.24.0
jedi==0.19.1
Jinja2==3.1.3
kiwisolver==1.4.5
Markdown==3.6
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
matplotlib==3.8.4
matplotlib-inline==0.1.7
mkl==2021.4.0
mpmath==1.3.0
networkx==3.2.1
numpy==1.26.3
opencv-python==4.9.0.80
packaging==24.0
pandas==2.2.2
parso==0.8.4
pillow==10.2.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.43
protobuf==5.26.1
pure-eval==0.2.2
Pygments==2.18.0
pyparsing==3.1.2
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
pytz==2024.1
six==1.16.0
stable-baselines3==1.6.0
stack-data==0.6.3
sympy==1.12
tbb==2021.11.0
tensorboard==2.16.2
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
torch==2.3.0+cu118
torchaudio==2.3.0+cu118
torchvision==0.18.0+cu118
traitlets==5.14.3
typing_extensions==4.9.0
tzdata==2024.1
wcwidth==0.2.13
Werkzeug==3.0.3

